# Is RTP-NL operational yet?

Tags: netherlands, customs-and-immigration

The Netherlands is implementing a Registered Traveller Programme to allow holders of certain passports to use the automatic gates at Schiphol (AMS) abbreviated RTP-NL. Announced last year, the implementation of that program has been delayed until Q1 2018, which is now. Does anyone know if that program is taking applications yet?

Comment: The schiphol rtp page now states end of 2018

Comment: The website for it has been taken down. It looks like it's not happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Schipol Airport](https://twitter.com/Schiphol/status/973138613440602112) tweeted about this earlier in the week.  The linked tweet is in Dutch, but translates roughly as:

> @ikorpershoek Hello Ies, thanks for your question. RTP-NL is currently
>   still in development in cooperation with the Dutch Government and
>   @Marechaussee. Unfortunately, We are unable to estimate the starting
>   date of RTP-NL at this time. ^ Job

So it's not operational yet, unfortunately.

Answer (score 7):

I was going through passport control and I was able to see that the signs to e-gates now have the RTP-NL sign hidden by a black sticker. You can also see the sign for where you can register for the RTP-NL Programme.

I asked Schiphol via twitter regarding this and I got an answer below:

> Thank you for your question! The latest update we have received about the re-introduction of RTP-NL stated that it is expected to be activated again in the second quarter of 2020. Those registered with RTP-NL can then become a Privium member at our airport without a European passport. More information will follow soon!

So if there are no more delays, we can probably expect it to be available sometime between April and July this year.

Answer (score 6):

Latest news you can read [here](https://insideflyer.nl/snelle-grenspassage-met-rtp-nl-en-global-entry-in-april-van-start/) (in Dutch). RTP-NL will restart in April this year.

Comment: Unfortunately, this seems to be delayed again, as registration still isn't possible as of April 3rd. In January of this year I reached out to the Ministry of Justice to ask about RTP-NL. I received a reply that the program would be operational in March. I reached out again in March to ask about the current status, but received no reply.

Answer (score 5):

**Update (June 23rd, 2022):**

It seems global entry applications for Dutch citizens will be opened up on **Monday, June 27th, 2022**. I received the following email from the Dutch ministry of Justice:

> Met veel genoegen informeer ik u dat de overheid vanaf aanstaande maandag 27 juni weer in staat is om Global Entry lidmaatschappen te faciliteren voor personen in het bezit van een Nederlands paspoort. Het aanvraagproces verloopt via de website van de CBP; Global Entry | U.S. Customs and Border Protection (cbp.gov).

> Een achtergrondonderzoek door de Koninklijke Marechaussee maakt onderdeel uit van het aanvraagproces. Hiervoor is het van belang om via de Berichtenbox berichten van de Koninklijke Marechaussee te kunnen ontvangen. Let er dus goed op dat deze mogelijkheid in uw Berichtenbox account geactiveerd is.

Translation:

> It is with great pleasure that I inform you that starting this Monday, June 27th, the government will again be able to facilitate Global Entry memberships for persons with a Dutch passport. The application process happens through the website of the CBP; Global Entry | U.S. Customs and Border Protection (cbp.gov).

> A background check by the Royal Military Police is part of the application process. To this end, it is important that you are able to receive messages from the Royal Military Police through your digital mailbox. So please ensure that this feature has been activated in your digital mailbox account.

---

I contacted the Dutch ministry of Justice regarding implementation of access to the Global Entry program for Dutch citizens. On April 5th, 2022, I received the following response:

> We zijn op dit moment erg druk met de laatste voorbereidingen ten behoeve van het faciliteren van Nederlandse Global Entry aanvragen.

> We wachten op de laatste vereiste goedkeuringen van de betrokken overheidspartijen om de voorziening formeel in operatie te kunnen nemen. Mijn inschatting is dat dit maximaal nog enkele weken tijd in beslag zal nemen.

Translation:

> We are currently very busy with the final preparations for facilitating Dutch Global Entry applications.

> We are waiting for the final required approvals from the relevant governmental stakeholders to formally activate this facility. My estimation is that this will take at most a few more weeks.

Comment: Then in a few weeks they would need another few weeks/months ? ;P

Answer (score 4):

I went through passport control (near Pier H) this week, and while there's a sign up near the Privium lane for RTP-NL registration, it's blacked out with no indication of when it's opening.

Comment: As another update, Schiphol Airport changed the RTP-NL launch date on its website from "Q1 2018" to "2018".

Answer (score 3):

The announcement mentioned [in this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/172967/128171) was correct and the Global Entry program is **now live** for dutch nationals.

See  https://www.cbp.gov/travel/trusted-traveler-programs/global-entry/international-arrangements/netherlands

> ## Application Process:
>
> Make sure you:
>
> - have activated your ‘Berichtenbox’ your digital mailbox on MijnOverheid;
>   have authorized Koninklijke Marechaussee (KMAR) to send messages to your account.
> - Apply online:  you will complete a [TTP online application](https://ttp.cbp.dhs.gov/) and pay the $100 non-refundable application processing fee.
> - Check your ‘Berichtenbox’ regularly after finalizing your Global Entry application.
>   You will receive a message from the Koninklijke Marechaussee (KMAR), the Dutch border police, asking you to confirm your Global Entry application and approve the background check.
>
> KMAR will then perform the background check.  CBP will include the result of the Dutch background check in their evaluation of the application.  You will receive a message from CBP with the result of your application.
>
> ## Maintaining Membership
>
> Once you have been approved for the program, the background check by the Dutch authorities will be repeated annually

Missing from there appears the in-person interview at either one of the scheduled interview locations listed [here](https://ttp.cbp.dhs.gov/schedulerui/schedule-interview/location) or the [enrollment on arrival](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/trusted-traveler-programs/global-entry/enrollment-arrival) alternative.

---

As far as I know there is no update yet though on second intended function of RTP-NL ; to open up the automated self-service passport checks for non-EU nationalities wishing to enter/leave the Netherlands at Schiphol airport.

Comment: Finally! I assume the second function would need to wait until the Schengen entry/exit system is finally implemented.

Answer (score 2):

> allow holders of certain passports to use the automatic gates

To answer the other part of the program, it was possible on July 9, 2022 to exit the Schengen area at Amsterstam Schiphol (AMS) using an automated gate with an adult (16+) biometric passport from Australia, Canada, Hong Kong, Japan, New Zealand, Republic of Korea, Singapore and the United States of America. The queues and the gates are the same for adult European (EU/EEA/Swiss) citizens with a biometric passport.

However, non-Europeans will be asked to see a designated border officer after the automated gates to obtain a passport stamp.

Using automated desks was not possible on July 31, 2022 to enter the Schengen Area via AMS for non-European citizens.

Full implementation of this program will only be possible once the electronic Schengen Exit/Entry record system goes into force, as at the moment the only enforcement mechanism for the 90/180 short-stay rule is through examining physical passport stamps.

---

[image: Panels at Amsterdam airport showing nationalities permitting self-service passport control]

Comment: *Full implementation of this program will only be possible once the electronic Schengen Exit/Entry record system goes into force* => but... don't they have to look for an entry stamp for exits too? It seems like it should either work for both entries and exits, or neither.

Comment: @JonathanReez the officer putting the passport stamp in the passport is supposed to examine the stamps that are already in it to evaluate compliance with the 90/180 rule.  Of course, doing so is usually impractical in the amount of time allocated to processing each passport.

Comment: @phoog right, that makes sense but I do wonder why the exact same process couldn't work for entries...

Comment: -1: Answer seems speculative and lacks any authoritative sources to support the conclusions drawn. (i.e. RTL-NL is somehow dependent on the implementation of Schengen Exit/Entry record system)

Comment: @JacobHorbulyk While I accept the criticism of lacking official source, I feel that I have explained "somehow" in the answer. Fully automated RTP-NL for non-EU travellers cannot be possible if Schengen continues to  rely on manually checking all entry/exit stamps within the last 180 days on a traveller's passport.

Comment: EES was also supposed to accompany a central Schengen RTP for non-EU travellers but instead the competency is finally reserved to member states. The Netherlands probably had a too optimistic timeline of its implementation (EU legal basis for EES/RTP passed in 2017). https://www.europarl.europa.eu/RegData/etudes/BRIE/2016/586614/EPRS_BRI%282016%29586614_EN.pdf

Comment: @JonathanReez I can only speculate but there may be a requirement for an officer to determine admissibility (e.g. health insurance) at entry (even if in practice questioning is rare) while for exit it can be that only overstay checks are carried out.

Comment: @JonathanReez On entry, you legally *have to* deny entry to people who have stayed too long in the past (in theory at least). On exit, you may want to use that opportunity to enforce the rule and impose a penalty but you can also choose not to bother, the person will be out of the Schengen area either way. Border guards cannot “deny exit” and aren't taking any decision.